# Show list of all the installed applications

Tags: ios, swift, share, airdrop

I am developing my application in `swift`. I want a feature like android or like `airdrop`. IT should work similar to the Airbnb application. On click of share button i want to show the list of all the app installed in the device and user can select anyone and share the data. 
I tried to search on google for the same but did not got any specific results.Any help would be appreciated 
Thanx.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `UIActivityViewController` for sharing purpose:

```
 @IBAction func shareButtonClicked(sender: UIButton)
        {
            let textToShare = "Swift is awesome!  Check out this website about it!"

            if let myWebsite = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com/")
            {
                let objectsToShare = [textToShare, myWebsite]
                let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)

                self.presentViewController(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't get access to other apps except in controlled ways.

Look at `UIActivityViewController` for ways to communicate with various social sites, and at `UIActivity` for customization tips.

The more general way to do data sharing with other apps on the device is through URLs.  Here's a link on [inter-app communication](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html).